# 0 solutions GridViewDataComboBoxColumn - How to show more columns on the edit form than the grid shows

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, devexpress

I have two Int columns which are displayed based on another table.
I would like to show only second (City) column data in the grid, but to show both fields in the edit form.
Is that possible?
Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gvOrders" ClientInstanceName="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataSourceID="sdsOrders" KeyFieldName="Id" Width="100%"
    OnRowInserting="gvOrders_RowInserting"
    OnRowUpdating="gvOrders_RowUpdating"
    OnCellEditorInitialize="gvOrders_CellEditorInitialize"
    OnInitNewRow="gvOrders_InitNewRow"
    OnStartRowEditing="gvOrders_StartRowEditing"
    OnDetailRowExpandedChanged="gvOrders_DetailRowExpandedChanged"
    OnRowInserted="gvOrders_RowInserted"
    OnRowUpdated="gvOrders_RowUpdated">
<SettingsCommandButton>
    <NewButton Text="New " />
    <EditButton Text=" Edit" />
    <DeleteButton Text="Delete" />
</SettingsCommandButton>

<Columns>
    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn VisibleIndex="6" Caption="Fitting Loc." FieldName="FittingLoc" Width="100">
    <PropertiesComboBox ClientInstanceName="cmbFitting" ValueField="LocId" EnableCallbackMode="true" Width="250"
        IncrementalFilteringMode="contains" DataSourceID="sdsFitting" TextField="City"
        EnableSynchronization="False" ValueType="System.Int32">
<Columns>
    <dx:ListBoxColumn FieldName="Address" Visible="false" />
    <dx:ListBoxColumn FieldName="City" Visible="true" />
</Columns>
<ValidationSettings>
    <RequiredField IsRequired="false" />
</ValidationSettings>
<ClientSideEvents EndCallback="cmbFitting_EndCallback" />
</PropertiesComboBox>
</dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
</Columns>
<Templates>
<EditForm>
<dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="EditorFitting" ReplacementType="EditFormCellEditor" ColumnID="FittingLoc"
runat="server"></dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement>
<div style="text-align: left; padding: 4px;">
<dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="UpdateButton" ReplacementType="EditFormUpdateButton"
    runat="server"></dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement>
<dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="CancelButton" ReplacementType="EditFormCancelButton"
    runat="server"></dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement>
</div>
</EditForm>
</Templates>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsOrder" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CoolCorpConnString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Order] ORDER BY SortOrder ASC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsFitting" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CoolCorpConnString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [LocId], [Address], RTRIM([City])+', '+RTRIM([State])+' '+RTRIM([ZipCode]) as [City]
    FROM [BusinessLocation]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

DevExpress 12.1.8, C#, SQL Server.
In the code above I gave only grid definition, two columns with locations definitions, part of edit form and SQL code to get data.

Full address takes too much space in the grid on the screen. Client currently has two locations in two different towns and states. Possibly will be third one. Company owner requires to see full address in the combobox in Edit/New form, but only town and state in the grid.

Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Serge, could you please give more information? What language, framework, library are you using, what are your goals and the context? The more information you give the better you are contributing to the community. Thanks.

Comment: I thought I did in tags... Sorry... 
DevExpress 12.1.8, C#, SQL Server. 
Full address takes too much space in the grid on the screen. Client currently has two locations in two different towns and states. Possibly will be third one. Company owner requires to see full address in the combobox in Edit/New form, but only town and state in the grid. 
In the code above I gave only grid definition, two columns with locations definitions, part of edit form and SQL code to get data. 
Thanks!

Comment: As this is valuable information to a person who reads the question, I would suggest you add it to the question itself. You can edit it.

Comment: Thanks! I did like you said... Any ideas how to resolve it?